# Vuetify v-checkboxes with v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-for

I am trying to use v-for to display all the checkboxes from the `backLogoLists` array.

I am using Vuetify. How do I use v-for in v-checkboxes? I keep getting this error when I uncheck for example logo2: 
`Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'undefined' in logo2"`

```
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="6" v-for="backLogoList in backLogoLists" :key="backLogoList">
    <v-checkbox v-model="backLogoList[key]" :label="backLogoList" :value="backLogoList"></v-checkbox>
  </v-col>
</v-row>

<script>
export default {    
    data: () => ({
        backLogoLists: ['logo1', 'logo2', 'logo3'],
    }),
};
</script>
```

Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

v-model refers to the property that will handle the value of the checkbox. You must use a unique property of the element as the key, not the primitive object. In this example I use 'text':

```
<template>
    <v-row>
        <v-col cols="6" v-for="backLogoList in backLogoLists" :key="backLogoList.text">
            <v-checkbox :v-model="backLogoList.selected" :value="backLogoList.text" :label="backLogoList.text"></v-checkbox>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            backLogoLists: [{selected:0,text:'logo1'}, {selected:0,text:'logo2'}, {selected:0,text:'logo3'}],
            //backLogoLists: ['logo1', 'logo2', 'logo3'],
        }),
    };
</script>
```